# Updating a score (int) WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, int

I am making an application in WPF, which is for a 'Ski Resort' which runs competitions. I have got it so it adds members, and these are added to a dictionary. I now need it so when the user searches for members, using there ID number, they can also update information such as name, address and score. So far it is updating the names and addresses which are stored as strings, but it's not updating scores. Here is the code for the constructor for the Skier:

```
public Skier(string inNumber, string inName,  string inAddress, int inScore)
    {
        name = inName;
        number = inNumber;
        address = inAddress;
        score = inScore;
    }
```

And there is method to set the score in the same class:

```
  private List<String> ScoreList = new List<string>(); //make a list for the scores

    public bool SetScore(int skiScore)
    {
        ScoreList.Add(name + "'s score is " + skiScore.ToString()); //add to the list
        skiScore = score; //set the score
        return true;
    }
```

In another class, is the method to add the member to the dictionary:

```
public Skier AddSkier (string inName, string inAddress, int inScore)
    {
        string newNumberString = newNumber.ToString();
        Skier result = new Skier(newNumberString, inName, inAddress, inScore);
        newNumber = newNumber + 1;
        Skier S = new Skier(newNumberString, inName, inAddress, inScore);
        Skiers.Add(newNumberString, S);
        return result;
    }
```

And in the main part here is the code which should update the score:

```
Skier activeSkier = new Skier(null, null, null, 0);
SkiLodge newSkiLodge = new SkiLodge("SkiLodge");

public void UpdateAccountScoreSkier (int newSkierScore) //update the score
    {
        if (!activeSkier.SetScore(newSkierScore)) //if cannot update
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid score"); //tell the user
        }
    }


  private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string updatedName = NameTextBox.Text; //get the new name
        string updatedAddress = AddressTextBox.Text; //get the new address
        string updatedScoreText = ScoreTextBox.Text; //get the new score
        int updatedScore = int.Parse(updatedScoreText); //convert to integer
        UpdateAccountNameSkier(updatedName); //call the update name method
        UpdateAccountAddressSkier(updatedAddress); //call the update address method
        UpdateAccountScoreSkier(updatedScore); //call the update score method
    }
```

Comment: Are you having a problem here: `string updatedScoreText = ScoreTextBox.Text;`, or here: `UpdateAccountScoreSkier(updatedScore);`? And can you show us the `SetScore()` method? You are currently showing us `GetScore()` even though your text says "method to set score".

Comment: Hi, here is the code for the set score:

          private List<String> ScoreList = new List<string>(); //make a list for the scores

        public bool SetScore(int skiScore)
        {
            ScoreList.Add(name + "'s score is " + skiScore.ToString()); //add to the list
            skiScore = score; //set the score
            return true;
        }

Comment: Hi thank you I have updated it now hopefully it'll be easier to understand

Comment: Change `skiScore = score;` to `score = skiScore;`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am so silly, its working now

Comment: @lucycopp you may want to take a look later on at data-binding and mvvm.